In what chapter does Fleur suspect Hagrid?
I am re-reading Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows and in chapter 6 it says:

We must decide ‘ow you will be disguised, ‘Arry,” said Fleur, once everyone had pudding. “For ze wedding,” she added, when he looked confused. “Of course, none of our guests are Death Eaters, but we cannot guarantee zat zey will not let something slip after zey ‘ave ‘ad champagne.” From this, Harry gathered that she still suspected Hagrid

But in which chapter does Fleur suspect Hagrid?

Why "suspect"? It seems to me she's implying that Hagrid might accidently let something slip after a drink or several.

This seems to be a reference to her little speech earlier in Chapter 5. Interestingly. it's Harry who does the suspecting, but obviously there's a notorious drunkard blabbermouth in the room when she says it.

‘You-Know-Who acted exactly as Mad-Eye expected him to,’ sniffed
Tonks. ‘Mad-Eye said he’d expect the real Harry to be with the
toughest, most skilled Aurors. He chased Mad-Eye first, and when
Mundungus gave them away he switched to Kingsley …’
‘Yes, and zat eez all very good,’ snapped Fleur, ‘but still eet does
not explain ’ow zey knew we were moving ’Arry tonight, does eet?
Somebody must ’ave been careless. Somebody let slip ze date to an
outsider. Eet eez ze only explanation for zem knowing ze date but not
ze ’ole plan.’
She glared around at them all, tear tracks still etched on her
beautiful face, silently daring any of them to contradict her. Nobody
did. The only sound to break the silence was that of Hagrid
hiccoughing from behind his handkerchief. Harry glanced at Hagrid, who
had just risked his own life to save Harry’s – Hagrid, whom he loved,
whom he trusted, who had once been tricked into giving Voldemort
crucial information in exchange for a dragon’s egg …

The fact that she then mentions that someone might speak out of turn after consuming alcohol all but confirms, to Harry, that it was Hagrid that she suspected all along.
